# slideToggle is not working on Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, function, slidetoggle

i'm try to add toggle menu on wordpress in mobile but the script is not working
but on normal website is working perfectly and when i try to add same script to wordpress template is not working

this is the script:

```
    <!--responsive toggle menu --> 
<div class="menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i></div>
<!-- Script for show menu -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
(document).ready(function() {
    (".menu-toggle").toggle(function() {

    }, function() {

    }).click(function(){
        ("#togglenav").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
    </script>
    <nav id="togglenav">
<ul>
<li><a href="<?=$site_url?>/" id="home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="<?=$site_url?>/concerts/" id="concerts">Concerts</a></li>
<li><a href="<?=$site_url?>/sports/" id="sports">Sports</a></li>
<li><a href="<?=$site_url?>/theater/" id="arts_theater">Arts &amp; Theater</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

**NOTE: console on chrome say: Uncaught TypeError: document.ready is not a function**

Comment: Its should be like : `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` and then use `$(".menu-toggle").toggle(function() {`

Comment: thanx  Rohil, but still not working!, what the final code look's  like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code is working fine.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".menu-toggle").toggle(function() {

    }, function() {

    }).click(function(){
        jQuery("#togglenav").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you @vel but is not working on wordpress this function is working on php normal website but on wordpress is not working the screen shot show the error 
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0tbAXwjk3SzYUpOb1RoMmxoNjg/view)

Comment: insert jQuery library file in header section

Comment: i already put the library on head section on header.php 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
when the library exist on the head section the error by console on chrome doesn't show any erro for this script
but is still not working when i click on toggle button 
@vel can i share with you my website to take a close look  ?

Comment: @Machine share your site

Comment: okay @vel, first transform your browser to responsive design mode at 320px
on this [link](http://www.ticketwood.com/) the script like on my question the script is working perfectly 
but on this [link](http://www.ticketwood.com/blog/) wordpress blog is not working whit the alert error on console chrome

Comment: this is html website. its working fine.  can you show me wordpress site

Comment: the link on my comment okay, [ link wordpress blog](http://www.ticketwood.com/blog/)

Comment: i change the $ and the script like this 
`    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".menu-toggle").toggle(function() {

    }, function() {

    }).click(function(){
        jQuery("#togglenav").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});    </script>` 
but still not working i donn't know why is working fine on php website and wordpress not working

Comment: replace this css #togglenav { display: none !important; background-color: #151515; }  with #togglenav { display: none; background-color: #151515; } line number 35

Comment: you are awesome 
i hate !important  :)
thank yooou soooo much!
it's working FINE